# What is the definition of product of ideal sheaves?

Tags: tag-removed, geometry

Each book on algebraic geometry write I^2 when it deal with nongsingular varieties, here I
is a ideal sheaf. But no one give the definition. I guess it's the sheafification. It's right?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the image of the map $I \otimes I \to O \otimes O = O$.

Comment: Thank you very much! I think this definition is equivalent to the above one.

Comment: Certainly it is since the sheafification functor is exact.